# Computing the Change of Basis Matrix between two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

For the two bases, $A$ and $B$ whose columns represent the basis vectors respectively, I was asked to find the transformation matrix from $A$ to $B$

$$ A= 
    \begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    2 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{Bmatrix} $$

$$ 
B= \begin{Bmatrix}
    -3 & 1 & 5 \\
    2 & -1 & 4 \\
    -2 & -1 & 9 \\
    \end{Bmatrix}
$$

I began by comparing the the basis vectors in $A$ to those in $B$ as per the definition of what the change of basis matrix is - it contains the coordinates of the new basis wrt to the old basis  e.g.

$$
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\ 
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) = x_1\left(\begin{matrix}
    -3 \\
    2 \\ 
    -3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) + x_2\left(\begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\ 
    -1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) + x_3\left(\begin{matrix}
    5 \\
    4 \\ 
    9 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) $$

And did so for all other columnns. This does seem like a tedious way to do things. Would I be right in thinking that I could identify the values of x, which are the coordinate representations of $A$ wrt $B$ by through the following relationship:

$A = XB$ and therefore, assuming $B$ is non-singular I could find the coordinates X by computing:

$AB^{-1} = X$ ?

If this is invalid could some explain why and perhaps suggest a quicker solution to such an equation?

Comment: If $X=B^{-1}A$ then for $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ we have

$$X[\vec{x}]_{\beta_A}=B^{-1}\Big(A[\vec{x}]_{\beta_A}\Big)=B^{-1}\vec{x}=[\vec{x}]_{{\beta}_B}$$

Comment: @MatthewHolder So it appears I have it the wrong way around, $AB^{-1} = X$ rather than $X=B^{-1}A$. From my working above could you point out my error please? At what stage did I make the wrong turn such that I mixed up the order?

Comment: You should have $A=BX$ instead of $A=XB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\ 
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) = x_{11}\left(\begin{matrix}
    -3 \\
    2 \\ 
    -3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) + x_{21}\left(\begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\ 
    -1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) + x_{31}\left(\begin{matrix}
    5 \\
    4 \\ 
    9 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) $ can be written as $$
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\ 
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
    -3&1&5 \\
    2&-1&4 \\ 
    -3&-1&9 \\
    \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
    x_{11} \\
    x_{21} \\ 
    x_{31} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) $$ Do you see how you $X$ matrix should be on the right and not the left?

Comment: @Matthew_Holder yes I do now you put it like that.